# using find and rename for their intended use

Tags: regex, bash, find, rename, xargs

Now before you face palm and click on duplicate entry or the like, read on, this question is both Theory and practical.

From the title it is pretty obvious what I am trying to do, find some files, then rename them. Well the problem, there is so many way to do this, that I finally decided to pick one, and try to figure it out, theoretically.

Let me set the stage: 
Lets say I have 100 files all named like this Image_200x200_nnn_AlphaChars.jpg, where the **nnn** is a incremental number and *AlphaChars* ie:

```
Image_200x200_001_BlueHat.jpg
Image_200x200_002_RedHat.jpg
...
Image_200x200_100_MyCat.jpg
```

Enter the stage **find**. Now with a simple one liner I can find all the image files in this directory.(*Not sure how to do this case insensitive*)

```
find . -type f -name "*.jpg"
```

Enter the stage **rename**. On it's own, rename expect you to do the following:

```
rename <search> <replace> <haystack>
```

When I try to combine the two with **-print0** and **xargs** and some regular expressions I get stuck, and I am almost sure it's because rename is looking for the haystack or the search part... (*Please do explain if you understand what happens after the pipe*)

```
find . -type f -name "*.jpg" -print0 | xargs -0 rename "s/Image_200x200_(\d{3})/img/"
```

So the goal is to get the find to give rename the original image name, and replace everything before the last underscore with **img**

Yes I know that duplicates will give a problem, and yes I know that spaces in the name will also make my life hell, and don't even start with sub directories and the like. To keep it simple, we are talking about a single directory, and all filename are unique and without special characters.

I need to understand the fundamental basics, before getting to the hardcore stuff. Anybody out there feel like helping?

Comment: For case insensitivity do `-iname` instead of `-name`.

Comment: If you know your files are in a single directory, ditch `find`.  `find` is perfect when your target files are scattered in a directory hierarchy, but in a single directory you'll find [glob or extended-glob patterns](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching) will do. Then you have: `rename "s/Image_200x200_(\d{3})/img/" *.jpg`

Comment: I love to simplify, thanks @glenn-jackman , but this find rename is obviously going to get more complicated, thus I use find, as the next step would be to do just that, recursively find and replace files and rename them, and it get's ugly later on with spaces in the names or special characters... but simple basic are important to start with :)

Comment: @glen-jackman using your suggested `rename 's/Image_200x200_(\d{3})/img/' *.jpg` does nothing on CentOS 5.5. Doing `rename Image_200x200_ img_ *.jpg` However works, but without the regex, is this maybe the problem...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another approach is to avoid using `rename` -- bash is capable enough:

```
find ... -print0 | while read -r -d '' filename; do
  mv "$filename" "img_${filename##*_}"
done
```

the `##*_` part remove all leading characters up to and including the last underscore from the value.

Comment: So it turns out the rename in CentOS and RedHat is NOT the perl version, explaining why it's not responding to the regular expressions I give it. It seems that this find-read-mv is my only solution for now. Thanks @glenn-jackman it works. Now to figure out what it all means, ie back to the books ...

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need `-print0` (i.e. you are sure your filenames don't contain newlines), you can just do:

```
find . -type f -name "*.jpg" | xargs rename 's/Image_200x200_(\d{3})/img/'
```

Which works for me:

```
~/tmp$ touch Image_200x200_001_BlueHat.jpg
~/tmp$ touch Image_200x200_002_RedHat.jpg
~/tmp$ touch Image_200x200_100_MyCat.jpg
~/tmp$ find . -type f -name "*.jpg" | xargs rename 's/Image_200x200_(\d{3})/img/'
~/tmp$ ls
img_BlueHat.jpg  img_MyCat.jpg  img_RedHat.jpg
```

What's happening after the pipe is that xargs is parsing the output of find and passing that in reasonable chunks to a rename command, which is executing a regex on the filename and renaming the file to the result.

**update**: I didn't try your version with the null-terminators at first, but it also works for me. Perhaps you tested with a different regex?

Comment: I just tried it step for step on my box and nothing happens. This is why I asked the question, as I thought I am doing something wrong. Using **Linux CentOS-55-64-minimal 2.6.18-274.17.1.el5 #1 SMP GNU/Linux** with _/usr/bin/rename_

Comment: Odd, I'm testing on debian, with `rename` from the `perl-5.10.1` package and `findutils` version `4.4.2-1+b1`. `Linux 2.6.32.33`.

Comment: Well CentOS 5.5 with `rename`from `util-linux-2.13-0.56.el5.x86_64` and `find` from `findutils-4.2.27-6.el5.x86_64`, another server with RedHat 6 using has the same sickness, it uses the same packages. I am stumped... Then I think I understand the theory... Somthing else is wrong I guess... but what...

Comment: The debian `rename` is actually `/usr/bin/prename`, maybe that makes a difference?

Answer (score 0):

What's happening after the pipe:

```
find ... -print0 | xargs -0 rename "s/Image_200x200_(\d{3})/img/"
```

`xargs` is reading the filenames produced by the `find` command, and executing the `rename` command repeatedly, appending a few filenames at a time. The net effect will be something like:

```
rename '...' file001 file002 file003 file004 file005 file006 file007 file008 file009 file010
rename '...' file011 file012 file013 file014 file015 file016 file017 file018 file019 file010
rename '...' file021 file022 file023 file024 file025 file026 file027 file028 file029 file010
...
rename '...' file091 file092 file093 file094 file095 file096 file097 file098 file099 file100
```

The `find -print0 | xargs -0` is a handy combination for more safely handling files that may contain whitespace.